# How do I program an atmega8 using Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, programmer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arduino as AVR Programmer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33/arduino-as-avr-programmer)

I am trying to upload a program to a separate chip Atmage8 on a breadboard. Do I just need to connect some wires from the Uno to the ISP of the breadboard mounted chip? Then I think I need something called AVRDUDE but not sure as I have also found this https://github.com/WestfW/OptiLoader Can some one give me some clear instructions on how to do this properly. Thanks

I need to upload also the timerone script i.e

ifndef TIMERONE_cpp
define TIMERONE_cpp

include "TimerOne.h"

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33/arduino-as-avr-programmer?rq=1) question.